# Generate scripts for trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using the below code get completed code of triggers in the selected database.

```
select [definition] +' ' + 'GO' 
from sys.sql_modules m
inner join sys.objects obj on obj.object_id=m.object_id
where obj.type ='TR'
```

Requirement: I would like to export the above trigger code as `C:\TMP\Trigger.sql` with help of T-SQL coding instead of Generate scripts using script wizard. I am not so strong in SQL Server. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: you could use the results to file option in ssms and mostly you will be fine, dont have an server to test currently,but i dont see an issue with your script

Comment: my requirement is I need to export results as .sql which can be integrated as job in sql which will run on different instance so I can go depend on GUI

Answer (score 1):

To schedule the scripting via a batch job, consider using a Powershell script or SSIS.  Powershell script example:

```
try {

    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll";

    $databaseName = "AdventureWorks2014";
    $sqlServerName = ".";
    $scriptPath = "c:\Scripts\TriggerScripts.sql";

    $SMOserver = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($sqlServerName);
    $scriptr = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($SMOserver);

    If (Test-Path $scriptPath) {
        Remove-Item $scriptPath;
    }

    $database = $SMOserver.databases[$databaseName]

    $objectsToScript = @();

    foreach($table in $database.Tables) {
        $objectsToScript += $table.Triggers;
    }

    $scriptr.Options.FileName = $scriptPath;
    $scriptr.Options.AnsiFile = $false;
    $scriptr.Options.AllowSystemObjects = $false;
    $scriptr.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = $false;
    $scriptr.Options.NoCommandTerminator = $false;
    $scriptr.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true;

    $null = $scriptr.Script($objectsToScript);

}
catch [Exception] {
    $e = $_.Exception
    $e.ToString();
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan .  Is there any way to simplify and use T-SQL code or PROCEEDURE instead of PS hence PS is restricted on our prod envt.

Comment: The tricky part of a T-SQL only solution is creating the file. How would you do that in T-SQL? If your organization has locked down Powershell, I would expect creating files in T-SQL to be an absolute no-no.  Maybe SSIS is acceptable middle ground.